# LinkedIn Preview (and open graph) images not displaying when sharing a webpage

Tags: image, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

For some reason anything my company tries to share on LinkedIn will post but the image will not load. Whether that is any images on the page or the Open Graph image that is specified for that page. I also understand that LinkedIn has a 7-day cache for images like this, but this has been ongoing for over a month now.

Here's an example: http://knowgreaterpartnership.com/100-days-in-a-minute/

```
<html lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">

<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="100 Days in a Minute" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Each week for the next 100 days, Buchanan&#039;s government relations professionals and attorneys will bring you 100 Days in a Minute, offering brief insights on President Trump&#039;s legislative and regulatory changes that will impact your business." />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://knowgreaterpartnership.com/100-days-in-a-minute/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://knowgreaterpartnership.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/100days-seo-facebook.jpg" />
```

When anyone tries to share this URL, the hyperlink will come up but no image. Now this page also has Open Graph meta tags to specify which image is shared.      The image URL is valid and works on both Twitter and Facebook, but not here on LinkedIn.

One workaround I know we can do is to X out of the blank image after pasting the URL and uploading a custom image. However, when doing this from our company's page this feature blocks any further adjustments to the post where we can tag any @ names associated with the post.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to check:

1. The dimensions 1600x900 and size of 220kb are within LinkedIn's requirements.  However, your aspect is 16:9 instead of 4:1 / 1:4.

> - Max file size: 1 MB
> - Minimum image dimensions: 80 x 150 pixels
> - Recommended aspect ratio: 4:1 or 1:4
>
> [Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)

---

2. Your image URI is https, it could be they are unable to retrieve your image.  Have you tried with an http image?

> Note: If the image meets the requirements, but it still does not
>   appear in updates on LinkedIn, your website may be blocking us from
>   pulling the image or the image may be located on a protected directory
>   or website.
>
> [Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)

---

3. Was the image change from the first time LinkedIn crawled your page for the image? They do cache for ~7 days.

> The first time that LinkedIn's crawlers visit a webpage when asked to
>   share content via a URL, the data it finds (Open Graph values or our
>   own analysis) will be cached for a period of approximately 7 days.
>
> This means that if you subsequently change the article's description,
>   upload a new image, fix a typo in the title, etc., you will not see
>   the change represented during any subsequent attempts to share the
>   page until the cache has expired and the crawler is forced to revisit
>   the page to retrieve fresh content.
>
> [Shared Content Caching](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin)